# Better Structure Query For Improved Performance

Tags: join, optimization, oracle12c

I was trying to perform a join on a query which works for the most part but its really slow. Is there a better way to structure this query in order to optimize its performance.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT(A.EMPLID),E.OPRID,E.OPRDEFNDESC,E.EMPLID,B.JPM_DATE_6,B.JPM_DATE_3,B.JPM_DATE_6,B.JPM_DESCR90 FROM (PS_JOB A LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_NPS_LICCERT_VW B ON A.EMPLID=B.EMPLID),PSOPRDEFN E
WHERE  a.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(e.EFFDT) FROM PS_JOB e
        WHERE E.EFFDT <= sysdate
        and e.emplid = a.emplid
        and e.empl_rcd = A.EMPL_RCD)
        AND a.EFFseq = (SELECT MAX(f.EFFseq) FROM PS_JOB f
        WHERE f.EFFDT = a.effdt
        and f.emplid = a.emplid
        and f.empl_rcd = A.EMPL_RCD)
        AND A.PER_ORG = 'EMP'
        AND a.paygroup not in ('SUM','CWR')
        AND A.EMPL_STATUS in ('A', 'L', 'P', 'S')
/
```

The result of the query is  as follows

```
OPRID   OPRDEFND    JPM_DESCR90 B.JPM_DATE_3    JPM_DATE_6  H.DESCR H.LOCATION
jszigeti    Julie   ELEMENTARY SCHOOL TEACHER           1-Feb-96    South St.   93
jszigeti    Julie   TEACHER OF THE HANDICAPPED          1-Dec-91    South St.   93
rleon   Roger   ELEMENTARY SCHOOL TEACHER       1-Jul-92    1-Jun-92    Off-Exec Supt   400
rleon   Roger   ELEMENTARY SCHOOL TEACHER       1-Jul-93    1-Aug-92    Off-Exec Supt   400
rleon   Roger   ELEMENTARY SCHOOL TEACHER           1-Aug-92    Off-Exec Supt   400
rleon   Roger   ELEMENTARY SCHOOL TEACHER           1-Jul-93    Off-Exec Supt   400
rleon   Roger   PRINCIPAL   1-Jul-98    1-Mar-98    Off-Exec Supt   400
```

The images for the explain plan for the query are attached

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeYMP.jpg).

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT8Ju.jpg)

[SCreenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbQKV.jpg)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to restructure and optimize my query by using the following SQL statements:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT(A.EMPLID),E.OPRID,E.OPRDEFNDESC,B.JPM_DESCR90,B.JPM_DATE_3,B.JPM_DATE_6 FROM PS_JOB A
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_NPS_LICCERT_VW B ON A.EMPLID=B.EMPLID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PSOPRDEFN E ON A.EMPLID=E.EMPLID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_NPS_VIEW_ALL H ON A.EMPLID=H.EMPLID
  WHERE  a.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(e.EFFDT) FROM PS_JOB e
        WHERE E.EFFDT <= sysdate
        and e.emplid = a.emplid
        and e.empl_rcd = A.EMPL_RCD)
        AND a.EFFseq = (SELECT MAX(f.EFFseq) FROM PS_JOB f
        WHERE f.EFFDT = a.effdt
        and f.emplid = a.emplid
        and f.empl_rcd = A.EMPL_RCD)
        AND A.PER_ORG = 'EMP'
        AND a.paygroup not in ('SUM','CWR')
        AND A.EMPL_STATUS in ('A', 'L', 'P', 'S');
```

This significantly reduced my wait time, and got be going to the next task